# Se presenta una marca de agua que no permite editar con el plugin WPBakery

Tags: wordpress

Recién el sitio obtuvo la licencia del Theme Cloudy7 y con él, el plugin WPBakery, pero al querer editar con este se presenta una marca de agua que no deja hacer nada. Adjunto imagen.
[image: Así se muestra al querer editar con el plugin]

Ya intenté desactivando todos los plugins excepto el WPBakery por si era problema de compatibilidad y no funcionó.
Bajé la versión de Wordpress de la 5.5.1 a la 5.3 y tampoco.

Muchas gracias por tomarlo en cuenta.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que es la imagen de carga del modulo y no una marca de agua. Lo más probable es que no haya cargado correctamente y quedo de esa manera.
Te recomiendo revisar la consola del navegador por si arroja algún error allí o contactarte directamente con el autor del tema.